# Pie React Chart

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, chart.js

I need the colors of the percentage numbers to be the same color as the graph, but every time I change the fill, it doesn't work

```
 [const config = {
    appendPadding: 10,
    data,
    angleField: "value",
    colorField: "type",
    radius: 1,
    innerRadius: 0.5,
    label: {
      type: "outer",
      offset: 13,
      style: { 
        fontWeight: 600,
        // fill:,
      },
    },
    color: ({ type }) => {
      return colorGraphPropsAfter.find(
        (task) => task.status?.alias.toLowerCase() === type.toLowerCase()
      )?.status?.color;
    },
  };


  return <Pie {...config} height={173} />;
};][1]
```

Comment: The color of what percentage? Labels on the chart, or in the tooltip? What does the data look like? I recommend you put together a working demo e.g. [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-chart-js-example-xmpmv7).